# URL File format multiple targets

Tags: url, file-format

The commonly accepted file format for a .url file (internet shortcut) is as follows:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://example.com
WorkingDirectory=C:\WINDOWS\
ShowCommand=7
IconIndex=1
IconFile=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\url.dll
Modified=20F06BA06D07BD014D
HotKey=1601
```

Is there a way, most likely a hack, to make a single internet shortcut file open up multiple tabs?  I tried this:

```
...
URL=http://example.com
URL=http://example.com
...
```

and this:
    ...
    URL=http://example.com; http://example.com
    ...
and the same thing with commas instead of semicolons.  I also tried with spaces after the semicolon/comma.  Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt that. Behind URL there is server IP address that must be found by your DNS server. I cant see a way to have couple of URLs in the same request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with HTML and JS, it is explained here:
http://www.bloggersentral.com/2009/11/opening-multiple-links-in-single-click.html

Comment: So I should make a html document, and have the content for that be something like this: <html> <head> <script type="text/javascript"> function new() { window.open("http://example") } </script> </head> <body onload="new()"> </body> </html> -- but what would I do to the javascript function to have it load more than one?

Comment: function new () { window.open(&quot;http://link/&quot;); window.open(&quot;http://link2/&quot;); }