# How to get a batch file open a website in default browser?

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I am fairly new to programming and as a bit of a fun thing I am building a vb.net console app to allow people in the band that I'm in to have easy access to all the relevant websites, e.g. Facebook, Twitter, the band website, etc.

So I have given up on getting vb.net to open the website and instead have learned how to make it run a batch file, but I just need to know what I need to put in it to open a website in the users default browser.

I have already tried:

```
start "" http://www.bandimin.co.uk
```

The vb.net code to run the batch file is:

```
If Console.ReadLine() = "1" Then
    Console.WriteLine("opening please wait...")
    Dim batfile1 As String batfile1 = "C:\Users\henry\source\repos\band console\band console\TextFile1.bat"
    Process.Start(batfile1)
```

But that is not working.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: `start "" http://www.bandimin.co.uk` should work in recent versions of Windows.  Maybe you need to post your batch file?  Or maybe you're calling the batch file incorrectly?

Comment: If Console.ReadLine() = "1" Then
            Console.WriteLine("opening please wait...")
            Dim batfile1 As String
            batfile1 = "C:\Users\henry\source\repos\band console\band console\TextFile1.bat"
            Process.Start(batfile1)

Comment: i know that i am calling it right as i get an error in console saying that start isnt a regognised command

Comment: but please explain how to do it correctly

Comment: Im struggling to work out how a batch file has anything whatsoever to do with your task. You should be able to invoke a command, or executable file directly from your VB code. You're already running a `.bat` file from VB, so why not run a `.url`? or a browser with a URL as its argument? Regardless of all that, what's the issue with just creating some `.url` files for their desktops, or even a simple `.html` file which contains all of the required hyperlinks. Just doubleclick the `.html` file and it should launch in a default browser, then just click on the links you need.

Comment: what is .url file and how do i make it

Comment: a URL is a uniform resource location.. I am sure you can understand from that how you can _"make"_ one. To give you a hint, it is the location of data, meaning a domain, a hostname etc, with the location of a file that presents the data to you. i.e http://somesite.com/ is the domain where http://somesite.com/index.html would be the URL, providing you the location of the required resources.

Comment: It's a plain text file. There's a general example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13088263), which should be explained better [here](http://www.lyberty.com/encyc/articles/tech/dot_url_format_-_an_unofficial_guide.html).

Comment: thanks for all your help so far i have now made the url file but i get the following error "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'
" when i call the url file

Comment: You don't really need all of the content in those examples, just try with the following command either from a batch file ot the Command Prompt: `@(Echo [InternetShortcut]& Echo URL=https://stackoverflow.com/q/63062442)>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\MyQuestion.url"`. The new shortcut should be on your Desktop, just double click it to try it in your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Process.Start()

```
Sub Main()
    Process.Start("http:\\www.microsoft.com")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

I cannot get the link in your question to work. Try it in your browser to see if it works.

Comment: thanks for the suggetion but i get this error System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.' as i am new to this i do not understand how to fix it

Comment: This is code in a Console application. There is no file. It opens a website in the default browser. Where are you attempting to run this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an temporary url file and then running it:

```
@echo off
echo [InternetShortcut] >> temp.url
echo URL=%url% >> temp.url
start temp.url
del temp.url
```